# How to change base url of Swagger in ASP.NET WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui

By default when you enable swagger in ASP.NET WebApi project is available on URL:

```
http://localhost:<random_port>/swagger/UI
```

I would like to use http://localhost:<random_port>/user instead of http://localhost:<random_port>/swagger/UI to access swagger. How/where can I configure that?

I found that for Asp.net core versions we can configure using RoutePrefix, but is there any similar method in ASP.NET Web API:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.RoutePrefix = "users";
});
```